# How to write and read to/from a CSV file - Oracle SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sqlplus

As a homework for the Database class, I have to write and read a table to and from a CSV file. I am not allowed to use any specific tool, I have to write my own procedures with which I have to achieve these goals. For example, the table I want to write is like this:

Students (id Integer, name varchar2(20), birth_date date).

In the CSV file, I would write something like this:

1,Brandon,--a date--

2,Alice,--another date--

3,John,--yet another date--

Keep in mind, where it says --a date-- and so on, it is a real date, I just didn't write it in the actual post.

Now, what our professor taught us is to use the UTL_FILE package to write actual stuff in a file, so I figured that it would be easy to just write in a file, using a cursor to go through the whole Students table and just writing in my file something like id || ',' || name || ',' || birthdate || '\n';

Now, the premise is that after saving the table in the CSV file, we have to drop the Students table and then repopulate it with the info from the CSV file.

I would greatly appreciate any form of help with both the Write and Read procedures and how to make them work. Again, writing seems easier, but reading seems more complicated.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Mihnea. You might find it helpful to read the FAQ before posting questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help Meanwhile I'm voting to close this question as "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Well, I'm not a professor, but I think you should look into SQL Plus - "spool" command. This will create a spool file with any extension you give that. Reading from csv or text, or delimited, or many other files can be done easily with Oracle SQL Developer. The UTL_File is good also if you must use PL/.SQL or cannot use tools as you wrote.

Comment: `utl_file` should work fine for writing. Let us know where you're stuck. You can either read the file back with `utl_file` as well, or else define an [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html). As a tip, I suggest using explicit formats such as `'YYYY-MM-DD'` for any `DATE` columns.

Comment: I have finished my homework and got a 10 for it. Was able to find a really cool way of reading from the CSV files using regexp_substr function. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the newer sqlplus utility from oracle called sqlcl. ( sql command line).
Then load using syntax 
SYNTAX – LOAD  [ table_name ] [ csv file with path ]
More options in [link](http://dbaclass.com/article/load-data-excel-sheet-oracle-table/)